# RUNDLL32.EXE powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0. Is it safe?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I searched this code ,for sleep mode in cmd windows 7, on the web:**RUNDLL32.EXE powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0**. Is it safe?

Answer (score 3):

Well... it shouldn't *damage* anything, but on the other hand, it only works through luck.

The SetSuspendState() function is [not suitable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043) for calling through rundll32. It takes three boolean values as parameters – but there's no way to specify that; rundll32 will always give it a specific list of parameters that *does not* match what SetSuspendState expects at all. (And no, the "0,1,0" will not be interpreted into bools or integers – the whole thing will be passed as a single string parameter.)

So after comparing [SetSuspendState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate) and [rundll32](http://web.archive.org/web/20001216065900if_/http://support.microsoft.com/support/kb/articles/Q164/7/87.ASP) parameter lists, it seems that you would end up passing a random non-zero value as bHibernate, a random non-zero value as bForce, and a random non-zero value as bWakeupEventsDisabled. If it *happens to* work, it's not exactly reliable.

I don't think Windows 7 comes with any tools which allow doing this properly (PowerShell *might* do the job), so I'd recommend using [nircmd standby](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) or [psshutdown -d](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) instead.